# Get matplotlib mapping between x, y values and pixel co-ordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a bunch of lines using matplotlib and finally at the end I want to create a bounding box on each such lines. I am also performing certain styling and transformation to keep the plot aligned. The problem is after all drawing, I am unable to find the mapping between my line's actual values and the pixel co-ordinates.

My code:

```
    # get data
    lines = get_lines()
    # styling and transformation
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    plt.axes().get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.axes().get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.axes().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    plt.axes().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    plt.axes().spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    plt.axes().spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    # plot each line
    for elem in lines:
        ls = elem['line_values']
        for subls in ls:
            data = np.array(subls)
            x,y=zip(*data)
            img = plt.plot(x,y,linewidth=2,c='black')
    # save the image
    plt.savefig(output_path, bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100)
    plt.gcf().clear()
```

The saved image is of size `640x480` but the min and max x value of any line was between 10000 and 20000.

So at the end (after drawing), can I find a map of how the actual values were plotted on the image?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial on _transforms_](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) ֎ I suggest that you [edit] your question to better explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib objects have transforms to convert between coordinate systems.

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html

Somewhere in your lines object, I think, you'll have minimum and maximum X and Y coordinates in the data coordinate system.  You can convert these values to the axes coordinate system, the figure coordinate system, or even the display coordinate system (which will have the origin outside the Matplotlib graph window unless you are in fullscreen mode).

If you want the whole 640 x 480 image, you want to count in pixels, and you want the top left corner to be the origin, use the transFigure() method of your current figure.

On another subject, I don't exactly see what you're doing with the img variable, it should be a Line2D object.